# Computing partial trace of a given kronecker product matrix with respect to the first component

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, kronecker-product

Suppose I have two matrices, given as:

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$, $B= \begin{pmatrix}
e & f \\
g & h 
\end{pmatrix}$

Then,the Kronecker product of $A$ and $B$ is

$A \otimes B=\begin{pmatrix}
ae & af & be & bf\\
ag & ah & bg & bh\\
ce & cf & de & df\\
cg & ch & dg & dh
\end{pmatrix}
$

So that the partial trace w.r.t $B$ is given as
$Tr_B\left(A \otimes B\right)= \begin{pmatrix}
ae+ah & be+bh \\
ce+ch & de+dh 
\end{pmatrix}$

Which can be obtained from $A \otimes B$ by just taking trace of each $2 \times 2$ block. However,the partial trace w.r.t $A$ is given as

$Tr_A\left(A \otimes B\right)= \begin{pmatrix}
ae+de & af+df\\
ag+dg & ah+dh 
\end{pmatrix}$

I did not understand how to obtain this expression from that of $A \otimes B$. Can anyone please help?

Comment: look at the 2x2 blocks formed by alternating rows and columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ denote the block matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{M_{11} & M_{12}\\
M_{21} & M_{22}},
$$
with each $M_{ij}$ of size $n \times n$. Then the partial trace with respect to the second component is given by
$$
\operatorname{tr}_2(M) = 
\pmatrix{\operatorname{tr}(M_{11}) & \operatorname{tr}(M_{12})\\
\operatorname{tr}(M_{21}) & \operatorname{tr}(M_{22})},
$$
as you have said. The partial trace with respect to first component is given by
$$
\operatorname{tr}_1(M) = M_{11} + M_{22}.
$$
In a sense, you are taking the "trace" of the matrix by adding up the **blocks** that appear on the diagonal.